# Getting 503 service unavailable from istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am creating istio service mesh and then trying to call an external service from istio pod.

I followed steps in link

```
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/
```

till

```
2 Verify that your ServiceEntry was applied correctly by sending a request to http://edition.cnn.com/politics.
```

but in place of "edition.cnn.com", used my service.

When I try to do curl inside my pod, I am getting the below error.

```
[2020-02-02T10:02:52.465Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 UF,URX "-" "-" 0 91 150 - "-" "curl/7.58.0" "fafa8680-bdf1-468a-b50f-1a4430707ceb" "service.abc.com" "173.25.13.66:80" outbound|80||service.abc.com - 173.25.13.66:80 10.44.0.6:47544 - default
```

I can ping to service.abc.com, but how do I debug this error, and how to get more logs for analysis? As it did not mention to create steps for mtls and destination rules in above link, I did not create them.

Note: I am not facing any issue with edition.cnn.com, but getting issues when using my service which is external to mesh and is running in another server within my company network.

Comment: Do I need to create any service? but it did not mention to create any service in above link.

Comment: when you use http://edition.cnn.com/politics what output you get? 301?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service.abc.com` service supports only http or only https or both http and https? Is it configured to redirect http to https ? if you hit an endpoint with http and if its neither listening on port 80 nor redirecting http to https you are expected to get 503.

If you follow all the steps till 5 in the doc and assuming that `service.abc.com` is a https service it should work as expected because at step 5 even if you are sending a http request istio egress gateway is going to convert it to https(TLS origination) before it sends out the request to `service.abc.com`.

Comment: service.abc.com will supports only https. At step5, istio will only redirect http to https? I no need to configure service.abc.com to redirect http to https?

Comment: You don't need to because Istio gateway will perform TLS origination and will open HTTPS connections to the external service while the original traffic is HTTP

Comment: here is the thing..if you do not configure redirection on service.abc.com then you will not get 301 when you send http request to it whereas if you configure redirection then will get 301 like you are getting for edition.cnn.com. But at step 5 Istio is going to send out https request to it so it should succeed regardless you configure redirection or not.

Comment: Do you know how do I pass client certificates to this  external https service?

Comment: Why do you need to pass client certificate ? Are tou doing mutual TLS between the pod and the external service? If not then you just need to provide it with server certificate of the external service.

Comment: It is a must to pass client certificate to that external service. We have SSLVerifyClient=require in apache httpd of that external service

Comment: You need redeploy the gateway with client certificate and the gateway will send that cert to that service when it initiates a HTTPS request https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#perform-mutual-tls-origination-with-an-egress-gateway